# Electron JS Visual Designer

Tags: electron

I am developing a cross-platform app using the Electron framework from electronjs.org and was wondering if there is such a thing as a visual designer for Electron app development. Just like how Visual Studio has the designer window for xaml files, so you can drag and drop buttons, text fields, etc. into your app design.

Comment: I just found this workaround for now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53112872/when-using-electron-what-is-the-best-way-to-design-the-html-css-layout/53113170#53113170

Comment: You can post that as an answer, and accept it. Doing so will help others who read this question in future.